# Can regular joint compound be used on blue drywall?

Tags: drywall

I bought a house that was being remodeled.

The bathroom has blue drywall on it.

Can i use regular joint compound on the drywall ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but it is meant as a backer for plaster veneer. 
As a little added info. Green board is used mostly in bathrooms, not blue board. In all of the bathrooms I have seen in homes I worked on, none has ever had anything other than regular mud over the joints. As an added bonus, blue board is supposed to have mildew resistant properties too.

Comment: It depends on your area , both green and blue are considered water resistant compared to standard Sheetrock and a “setting” type or hot mud is normally recommended in a bathroom where the humidity is high. Hot mud will also be water resistant but standard joint compound will work fine if moisture is not a problem.

Comment: Green and blue board are useless.   I have done tests and unless you are happy with something that takes slightly more time to mold then they really serve no purpose.   It is like a marine spraypaint I used for a boat a few years back made for rust/corrosion.   Instead of lasting 4-5 years it lasted 5.5 years... like who cares.   I should have spent slightly more money, got the primer that last 15...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a bathroom the right way it has nothing to do with green, blue, white, or whatever color board and it has nothing to do with joint compound or hot mud or plaster or spackle.

1. Use whatever board you want, city may say green - so use it.   But know that green board molds just like regular drywall.  It is like comparing cardboard to corrogated cardboard.   Yes one may be stronger but they both break and tear.
2. Use whatever you want to smooth walls - joint compound is fine.
3. Use a oil based primer.   This will provide an almost impenetrable shell for light water and steam - I will give 3 coats near showers/tubs.   So when painting it is oil based primer + oil based paint or oil based primer, latex primer, latex paint.

This is the standard of any bathroom I do.   I think it is hilarious people talking about greenboard (and cities asking for it) but then just basic latex paint/primer-in-one is suitable.   It is the paint shell that protects the drywall - drywall not matter what type is terrible at protecting itself.     To me cities should have painting standards or make bathrooms all fiber board.

This is also one of those things where you do it right, it takes an extra half hour and $20 in primer and it is basically there the lifetime of the bathroom.   They can repaint, change colors, add wallpaper whatever and that shell is still there.